# Adding an event to a button created at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Please refer to the code below:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#btn").click(function() {
        alert("Hello");
     );

     $("a").click(function() {
        addButton();
     });
  });

  function addButton() {
     var par = document.getElementById("#div1");
     var bElem = document.createElement("button");
     var id = document.createAttribute("id");
     id.value = "btn";
     bElem.setAttributeNode(id);
     parent.appendChild(bElem);
  }
</script>
```

So what I'm trying to do is to create a button at runtime and then add an id attribute to it. But when I use the `$("#btn").click(function()` it does not work. When I create the button not at runtime, I can perform the function well. How will I do this?

Additional Info:
My created button is inside a div.

Comment: The problem is that you are adding the event handler at document.ready but at that time the button does not exist. Either use delegation or attach the handler in your addButton function. An aswers explaining how is already posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use [***event delegation***](https://api.jquery.com/on/) for that

```
$(document).on("click","#btn",function(){

});
```

Event delegation allows you to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all children matching a selector, whether those children exist now or are added in the future.

It is considered good practice to use an `#id` selector as close to the element (in this case `#btn`) as possible, which doesn't load dynamicly. Think `#container` or `#formWrapper`.
The reason for this is event bubbling. An event bubbles all the way the starting selector (`document` being the root element). If you add a more narrow parent element, it will be less intensive.

**edit**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    addButton();
});
});
$("#div1").on("click", "#btn", function () {
    alert(1);
});

function addButton() {
    $("#div1").append($("<input/>", {
        type: "button",
        id: "btn"
    }));
}
```

Comment: It does not work, can you elaborate how would I apply this? is it still inside the document.ready?

Comment: thanks man it already works! And also I learned from your code the proper adding of elements using jQuery. Better than my javascript code that takes lots of lines.

Comment: I only know the basics of jQuery(learned from w3schools), would you recommend a better place(site or book) to study it, a more complete one?

Comment: But this function creates multiple buttons with the same ID.

Comment: @krato: jquery.com, just browse around to check out the options. That's how I started. Familiarise yourself with their train of thought